# How to wait for multiple fetches to complete in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to wait for two `fetch()` API calls and then to save data from each fetch to different window object. I found this article https://gomakethings.com/waiting-for-multiple-all-api-responses-to-complete-with-the-vanilla-js-promise.all-method/ and tried following code to wait for the API calls:

```
Promise.all([
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
]).then(function (responses) {
    // Get a JSON object from each of the responses
    return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }));
}).then(function (data) {
    // Log the data to the console
    // You would do something with both sets of data here
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (error) {
    // if there's an error, log it
    console.log(error);
});
```

However when pasting this in browser console, the result is not being logged.

**What is wrong with the code and how to wait for both to be resolved?**

Comment: what if any of the request fails?

Comment: Which return are you talking about?

Comment: It looks fine, you will get final data at `console.log(data);`

Comment: Your code looks fine and its prints the data after both the promises are resolved. Not sure of the issue you are talking about

Comment: When pasting the code in the console, the result is not logged @VinuPrasad

Answer (score 5):

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const responsesJSON = await Promise.all([
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'),
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2')
    ]);
    const [todoOne, todoTwo] = await Promise.all(responsesJSON.map(r => r.json()));
    console.log(todoOne, 'todoOne');
    console.log(todoTwo, 'todoTwo');
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

fetchData();
```

Might be looking for something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this thing. I tested it on a fiddle and it looks like it works.

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"),
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2")
]).then(responses =>
  Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json()))
).then(data =>
  console.log(data)
).catch(err =>
  console.log(err)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```js
let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";

async function doRequest() {
  let toDo1 = await (await fetch(url + "1")).json();
  console.log(toDo1);
  let toDo2 = await (await fetch(url + "2")).json();
  console.log(toDo2);
}

doRequest()
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This way, if you need to fetch multiple items, you can use a loop inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on my side. I was accidentally filtering the browser console. However thank you all for your help.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

please use axios for fetch data in js . react or angular etc...

https://github.com/axios/axios
please install with npm and read doc

```
$ npm install axios
```

```
axios.get('/user')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    axios.get('/user')  .then(function (res) {
     console.log(res);
    })
  })
```

when first req is finish,
then start req sec

Comment: Why are you recommending a library instead of figuring out the actual problem?

Comment: Because the solution becomes easier.
This library gives us better facilities