# Multiple fetches writing to an array state variable cause inconsistent state

Tags: reactjs

**I can have individual state variables for every `fetchComplete` and check them as individual variables, and that works perfectly, but here I'm using an array to collect fetch statuses.**

I have an array state variable `flashingBoxLoaderItems` that will collect the "receipts" from individual async fetches happening in the component, to let me know when all the fetches are complete. There's also a boolean variable `flashingBoxLoaderComplete` that is set on an `Effect` monitoring any changes on `flashingBoxLoaderItems` to hide the loader when everything's done.

```
const [flashingBoxLoaderItems, setFlashingBoxLoaderItems] = useState<string[]>([]);
const [flashingBoxLoaderComplete, setFlashingBoxLoaderComplete] = useState(false);
```

Example of fetches. Note that the state variable is correctly updated for the Effect using the spread ... syntax, so the effect does pick it up.

```
const fetch1 = async() => {
   try {
    const response = await get<any>("/url1/");
    //...
   } catch {
    //...
   } finally {
    setFlashingBoxLoaderItems([...flashingBoxLoaderItems, 'fetch1']);
   }
}
// ETC. - Same for fetch2(), fetch3(), etc.
```

Effect to check all the receipts and set the final `complete` variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let fetchesExpected = ['fetch1','fetch2','fetch3','fetch4','fetch5'];
    let result = fetchesExpected.every(i => flashingBoxLoaderItems.includes(i));
    setFlashingBoxLoaderComplete(result);
}, [flashingBoxLoaderItems]);
```

But this doesn't work correctly. The debugger shows that my `flashingBoxLoaderItems` doesn't grow incrementally as expected. Sometimes it has 1 or 2 strings instead of the expected 4 or 5 on the 4th or 5th fetch. My suspicion is the fetches all happen at different times and the array isn't being synchronously maintained. So the `complete` variable at the end never gets set to TRUE after the 5th fetch as it should.

The code that does work is if I simply `flashingBoxLoaderItems.push('fetchN')` after each fetch. But in that case, since there's no state variable change, there's no re-render. I never get the chance to re-render and hide/show the loader.

Comment: Can't use wrap it in `Promise.all() ` ?

Comment: Can you show an example, as it would be used in this specific code?

Comment: Please see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635290/how-to-wait-for-multiple-fetches-to-complete-in-javascript) for an example.

Comment: Why do I need promises if I'm using `await`? Also, I'd prefer not to drastically alter the structure of the `fetchN()` methods. Is there a way to keep an array of Promises and check their status, to keep with this array approach? I could easily have individual variables to let me know when a particular item is done, but we're doing this array approach.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to validate that all your requests have been completed would be using the Promise.all() method.

You can set your urls or promises executions inside a map something like:

```js
const promises = [fetch1(), fetch2(), fetch3()];

async function resolvePromises() {
  const results = Promise.all(promises) // now you have the result of every promise inside results array. 
}
```

once the promises are resolved you can set the results in a state.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately our app isn't written like that. Everything is split up into individual fetch methods, and each has its own try/catch/finally.

Comment: Have you thought about mapping your promises into a for loop? These can be asynchronous with the disadvantage that you will block the execution of the program until all requests are finished. 

If this does not work for you i think you should provide more information about when and how you are calling your functions.